# Attempting to generate a list in R using replicate

Tags: r, replicate

I'm working through exercises in DataCamp through a course I'm currently taking on EdX.

The specific question I'm stuck on requires me to create a list (l) of all possible outcomes in remaining games.

The number of remaining games is:

```
n <- 6
```

I have my simple vector outcomes here which has a 0 for a loss and a 1 for a win.

```
outcomes <- c(0,1)
```

Now, the specific part of the question I'm struggling with is: "Assign a variable l to a list of all possible outcomes in all remaining games. Use the rep function to create a list of n games, where each game consists of list(outcomes)"

Here's my code:

```
l <- replicate(n, sample(outcomes, n, replace=TRUE))
```

Now, I think my biggest problem here is that I'm only generating n amount of games when I should be generating the total number of games possible. I'm not exactly sure how to do this and even after looking over documentation, I've been stuck for awhile.

Thanks for any and all help. Also, is this proper etiquette for this type of question?

Comment: If you're familiar with expand.grid, you could rep the one-game outcome six times and pass it there for a start, `rep(list(0:1), 6)`. Btw rep and replicate are different functions and you can compute the correct length as `length(outcomes)^n`, look up the "fundamental principle of counting" if unsure why

Comment: Are you looking for all possible outcomes that are possible from your set (0,1) for `n=6` games, such as `000000`, `000001`, `000010` , ... , `111111` ?

Comment: I might be dopey, but I have no clear idea what the Datacamp question wants. If their goal was to write a confusing question, they've succeeded.

Comment: Oh wow! I completely missed that they may have been different functions, but you're absolutely right that helps a lot. Thanks so much for this.

Comment: Yes, Nishan. I am looking for all the combinations of 0's and 1's for n rows.

Comment: Originally, I had used expand.grid like this:                                                         possibilities <- expand.grid(c(0,1), c(0,1), c(0,1), c(0,1), c(0,1), c(0,1)) but DataCamp will only accept the answer using the rep function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get all possible outcomes by using a list of outcomes with `rep()` and `expand.grid()`:

```
n = 6
outcomes = c(0,1)
l = rep(list(outcomes), n)
> expand.grid(l)
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
1     0    0    0    0    0    0
2     1    0    0    0    0    0
...
63    0    1    1    1    1    1
64    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Ahhh! This helps so much. I thought I would see the entire list through the use of rep, but I see that you need to use expand.grid on l instead. I had the right idea of how to use expand.grid initially, but this clears everything up. I appreciate the help!